# Application is in break mode - Cannot diagnosticate the code

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have the following code design:

```
public class Program
{  
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
           DoWork(); //<- This method will throw exception
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
 }
```

when my application crash I cannot see the line of code that have generated the exception, but the code will go automatically inside the `catch` block, I try also to remove the `try / catch` block but the application will fall in:

> Application is in break mode

So i tried to switch on the `debug information settings` for generated the `.pdb` file and I setted as `Full`, the `.pdb` file are generated but I still cannot debug the application on the specified code line that have generated the exception.

Consider that if I set a breakpoint on `Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());` I can see the `stacktrace` but for me isn't the easy way to debug an application, I need to access directly on the line of code for see the variable value and other stuff.

How can I manage that? Thanks.

Comment: @DrNachtschatten I need to debug the exception on the line which have caused it

Comment: Could you post the Stack Trace? Did you check the method your stack trace points at?

Comment: @DrNachtschatten I can debug the exception using `ex`, what I need is see the value of the variables on the code line which have generated the exception that's it.

Comment: Basic counter-measures are Tools > Options > Debugging > untick "Just My Code" and Project > Properties > Debug > tick "Enable native code debugging".  That still does not give you a guarantee that the debugger can now find the code.  You must use the stack trace to identify the module that contains the bad code.  The Debug > Windows > Modules can tell you more about it.  Right-click it and select Symbol Load Information to find out where it searched for the pdb.

Comment: @HansPassant this should be an answer.

Comment: Meh, there is going to be another question about it and I know I can't answer that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a related post [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/104485/the-application-is-in-break-mode-1.html)

> Debug > Options > General > Uncheck "Enable Just My Code"